# ios cordova app stuck at deviceReady event

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have added both Android and iOS platform to a cordova app. Android version builds and run fine. When I try to run the ios application from Xcode the simulator gets stuck at cordova splash screen "Device is ready".
In the Xcode console window it says only: `Received Event: deviceready`.

In the simulator system log I get the following error all the time:

Simulator error log

[image]

have anyone experienced this before?
any suggestions?

Comment: In Safari, open the web inspector for that instance and check the JS console. Also please provide the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: i have created a new cordova app and merged an angular 4 app into it. Android version is working fine. How can i run the instance in Safari?

Comment: You don’t run it in Safari, you run it in the Simulator or device and use Safari’s web inspector to debug it. In the Developer menu, select the relevant instance. In some cases you may need to restart Safari to make the instance appear in the menu. For actual devices you need to enable the web inspector in Settings.